# How to make fingerprint and decode in webrtc sdp

Tags: webrtc, dtls

now I need to make webrtc SDP -> normal SDP.

so I need to encode and decode fingerprint in webrtc.  I think that fingerprint is SRTP encrypt method.

anyone have experience decode and encode fingerprint. I need following step

WEBRTC SDP -> signal server(decode fingerprint,  make normal rtp SDP) -> sip client.

sip client SDP(normal rtp) -> signal server(encode fingerprint, make webrtc sdp) -> WEBRTC.

and we decode and encode SRTP in turn server...

please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The certificate that is used to encode/decode the SRTP stream is negotiated through DTLS. You need to get the master key from the DTLS negotiation. You cannot do that through packet sniffing. You will have to use the native API and use your own certificate to decode the stream.

You will have to do something similar to the [WebRTC Breaker](http://webrtc2sip.org/) to get the raw rtp stream. That breaker does everything you need it to and it is GPL.